# How to create mongodb client using php7 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mongodb

I just want to create mongoDB client(1.2.9) using PHP7 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I Just getting error from Apache log as below.

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb:/192.168.0.160:27017' in /var/www/html/db.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/db.php(4): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->__construct('mongodb:/192.16...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/db.php on line 4

Comment: `mongodb://192.168.0.160:27017` you were missing a slash `/`

Comment: after adding "/"  i got  this error                                                                                              [Thu Aug 10 15:42:20.567779 2017] [:error] [pid 26566] [client 192.168.0.203:51667] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\RuntimeException: not authorized on testDb to execute command { find: "testColl", filter: { age: 30 } } in /var/www/html/db.php:10\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/db.php(10): MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager->executeQuery('testDb.testColl', Object(MongoDB\\Driver\\Query))\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/db.php on line 10

Comment: Well that's because you did not provide a username or password as required. It's also what we call a **different question** here. If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I getting this type error,[Fri Aug 11 09:30:05.985765 2017] [:error] [pid 31307] [client 192.168.0.203:57805] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager::$admin in /var/www/html/mongo.php on line 8
[Fri Aug 11 09:30:05.985829 2017] [:error] [pid 31307] [client 192.168.0.203:57805] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/mongo.php on line 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this mistake in connection url :

```
mongodb://192.168.0.160:27017
```

after: `mongodb:` need two **`//`** or you choose a database php can't connect to mongo database read this [issue](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/issues/171).